# escape unescape string with bash compatible in ruby

Tags: ruby, bash

There is a line obtained by reading from the file. How to escape this line keeping compatibility with bash? I found a suitable solution using shellestsape but how i can unescape this line? When I use it in RoR application, I get a error invalid byte sequence utf-8.

```
line = File.open(path,'rb').read.shellescape

passline = \`./my_app 1 #{line}\` - all right, it`s return filename

out = \`./my_app 2 #{passline}\` 

out = "\\▒\;aQ\▒\;aQux\\\\▒\\\▒\                                                                                    J,R\▒bg8\?\▒\▒\▒\▒\▒\\▒f\▒\(L\▒e\`dc\▒\▒\#\▒lNljs\▒5\▒`P\▒\\▒" -
```

it`s binary file but shellescaped - how I can unescape it and save as file?

Comment: did you put a magic encoding on top of your ruby script? `#encoding utf-8`

Comment: phoet,this line exist in my script

Comment: does this help you http://mikenaberezny.com/2008/04/28/parsing-quoted-strings-in-ruby/